# How to get the user defined name for the network drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

I have a problem with name of network drive. 
If we go to the properties of the network drive, we can see two names, one is on the title (the user-defined name), the other is beside the icon (the label).
I tried to use GetVolumeInformation function to get the name of the network drive. The name I got is the label of that network drive, not user-defined name.
With what function can I get the user-defined name?

Comment: I think if `GetVolumeInformation()` has not provided what you need then there is no other method that could give you that info. Just confirm if it really didn't work. Try to use the `SetVolumeLabel()` and then try again `GetVolumeInformation()` and see if it gives you the label name that you provided in `SetVolumeLabel()`. As per docs A label is a user-friendly name that a user assigns to a volume to make it easier to recognize.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The user defined name can be edited just by right click and rename. The thing is that the user defined name and label for the local disk are the same. But they are different for the networks drive. SetVolumeLabel will set the label, but not the user defined name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a work-around solution. The user-defined name is stored in the registry, sub keys in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2. First I used WNetGetUniversalName to get the path of the network drive, then transformed the path to the corresponding name in the registry and read the value from _LabelFromReg.